# Dynamically sized side-by-side floats

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="list-container"> </div>
<div id="button-container"> </div>
```

And the CSS for these two divs:

```
#button-container {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#list-container {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FAD275;
}
```

Both of these divs are side-by-side and have the same height. The `button-container` div is on the right and must have a fixed width of `100px`. The left div, however, named `list-container` needs to have a width equal to the remaining space allocated by the parent container. So for example, if my parent div has a width of `400px`, and the `button-container` div takes up `100px` of that, then I should be able to specify something like `height: 100%` for the `list-container` div and have that equal to a width of `300px`.

The absolute #1 rule is that I cannot set a fixed width for the `list-container` div. The parent div for this whole thing is dynamically resizable, so every child underneath it must be designed to resize with it, hence why this question exists.

Keep in mind that this is all being done in a Google Chrome extension, so I have access to HTML5 and CSS3. I also don't need to worry about cross-browser support. I only want this to work in Chrome.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make `list-container` fill the remaining space of the parent container without using a fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`.

This mimics the way a table handles its rows, but applies it to divs.

You'll need a wrapper div, but that's all the extra markup you'll need.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<div id="list-container">list container </div>
<div id="button-container">button container </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#button-container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#list-container {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FAD275;
}
```

See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/p4dvU/).

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason in my real code it isn't working. I add a button to my `button-container` and it gets pushed to the bottom for some reason. Can anyone explain this? Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/p4dvU/9/

Comment: It should be at the top inside the `button-container`. This is where it is normally placed without introducing `display: table`

Comment: Just add `vertical-align: top;` to the button container and as a note `<ul>` is not a valid self closing tag. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/p4dvU/11/

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I'm not a seasoned web developer, so I appreciate the tips. For future reference, is there a list of valid self-closing tags somewhere?

Comment: Kyle, vertical alignment helped with the button-container, however for some reason my list-container is only 230px high instead of 250px. When I remove `display: table-cell;`, it goes back to 250px like it should and still looks great. Is it safe to remove the table-cell display attribute from my list-container? Why are there 20px missing at the bottom of this div? It looks like it is being treated as padding even though padding has 0 in Chrome's web dev tools.

Comment: Remove display: absolute; as it's not a css property, it's either display: block/*or other options*/; or position: absolute/*other options*/. And set padding to 0 on the body. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/p4dvU/13/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I found out that my `box-sizing: border-box;` on my `#list` was causing the problem. I don't know why but removing it fixes it :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the left container to 100% and give it a right margin of 100px.  My original answer said padding too, but thats wrong. The margin creates room for the floating right div. The percent widh allows the left div to dynamically resize.

Comment: I actually can't get this to work at all. No matter what I try, even with a 100px margin on the list-container, my button-container gets pushed out and hangs below my parent div. I can't get them to be side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

This site may be helpful to you:

http://glish.com/css/

Comment: Could you point out which article in particular I'm supposed to be interested in?