# Aligning a 100% width div to a fixed width div

Tags: css, html

Consieder the following please:

```
.d1 {
width: 100px;
float: left;
}

.d2 {
width: auto;
float: left;
}

<div class="d1">Content fixed</div>
<div class="d2">This content should take the rest of the page (on vertical side)</div>
```

This does not work.
How can I let a fixed width div stay on the left of a variable (window adaptive) width div?

Thank you.

Comment: width auto will size depending on the content contained in it. Have you tried surrounding both divs with a wrapper div to control the overall width that way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically sized side-by-side floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461912/dynamically-sized-side-by-side-floats)

Comment: This has been asked a lot of times on SO, there are lots of answers, try searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `float` from `.d2` and giving it a left padding equivalent to `.d1`'s width will do the trick:

```
.d1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.d2 {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/mZHcj/1/).

Comment: The problem is that the text, as I insert it, makes go down the content of the other div...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to give the `.d2` a `position:absolute`, then a `left:100px` and a `right:0;`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/La6QP/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of width:auto try width: 100% (or 90% / 99% etc) for the larger div.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your current styling from d2 and give it some margin.